# R - write/read data frame to file including attributes

Tags: r, file-io, attributes

I have a data frame with somewhat difficult-to-understand feature names, so I have an attribute that gives more description for each column. However, if I write this file using `write.csv` the attribute doesn't get included in the file. The function `write.arff` *does* actually write something called "attribute" to file, but it's just additional column information like data type and factor labels/levels. When reading the file back in to R with `read.arff`, it doesn't appear that this additional info is brought back in with the rest of the data.

Is there a way to write a data frame to standard file type (csv, xml, fixed-width text, tab-separated) with its attributes intact?

I understand that there are functions like `save` and `dput`, but I need the body data to be able to be read by other programs too, like Excel, KNIME, or SPSS. The attributes I'll probably be using only in R, but if possible I'd like to keep them in the same file with the data. Thanks!

Here's an example of the attribute:

```
> attr(hipparcos, 'desc')
[1] "Identifier (HIP number) (H1)"                    "*[HT] Proximity flag (H2)"                      
[3] "? Magnitude in Johnson V (H5)"                   "*[1,3]? Coarse variability flag (H6)"           
[5] "*[GHT] Source of magnitude (H7)"                 "*? alpha, degrees (ICRS, Epoch=J1991.25) (H8)"  
[7] "*? delta, degrees (ICRS, Epoch=J1991.25) (H9)"   "*[*+A-Z] Reference flag for astrometry (H10)"   
[9] "? Trigonometric parallax (H11)"                  "*? Proper motion mu_alpha.cos(delta) ICRS (H12)"
```

Correction: the .arff file does *not* write the attribute to file - it writes data type, factor labels and column name and calls them "attributes". My mistake!

Comment: How do you plan on using those attributes in other programs?  Could you have two files, one for attrs and one for data, in one directory?

Comment: Then I would probably use `write.csv` to write the data only, then `writeLines` to append the attrs to that file.  Then be careful when reading it in, possibly use `count.fields()` to determine the lines

Comment: What do you use to read in that data written with `writeLines`? `readlines`?

Comment: You can use `readLines` for character vectors, or `scan`

Comment: You should a) post the output of `dput(.)` on a test case with the required level of complexity, b) specify what it means to require that other programs can read it, and c) delete all the comments that should have been edits to the question and put them back into the question body.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this one? I'm asking a similar thing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787126/convenient-way-to-write-variables-label-to-csv-after-importing-stata-data-wit

Comment: @RAndStata This was back when I was doing my master's, so I don't remember exactly but I think I think I went back and tried a different approach. I never found a satisfying answer to this exact question. Sorry! Maybe you'll have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

If it can help to someone, I have used the following code:

```
library(rlist)
file <- attr(hipparcos, 'desc')
list.save(file, 'your//pathway//file.yaml')
```

The yaml file can be opened with a text editor